# Why doesen't css file apply on html file - Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a problem that my .css file doesn't apply on my .html file in Django. But when I, for example, type . some class name from the .html file, pycharm offers me to finish the class name. So, I think its linked right.

Anyway, I put in my settings file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Run `python manage.py collectstatic` succesfuly and added my .css file to .html with command:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'base.css' %}"/>
```

Inside of my project I have something like this:

```
-website
   -static
        -admin (generated when I run the command above)
        -images
        -base.css
    -templates
        -navbar.html
        -base.html
     -app1
     -app2
     -etc
```

For testing purpose I just put simple div in the head section of the .html file:

```
 <div class="example">jvhgbhjgf</div>
```

And in .css file:

```
.example { background-color: red; border-radius: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your settings.py file like following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static_dirs'),
    )
```

and directory's tree:

```
-website
-static
    -static_root
        -admin (generated when I run the command above)
    -static_dirs
        -images
        -base.css
-templates
    -navbar.html
    -base.html
 -app1
 -app2
 -etc
```

add base.css file in static_dirs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns [ ... ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: It's the same, nothing happened. :(

Comment: After I did what you wrote in your previous response I can access, but, still, it wasn't applied on .html file.

Comment: I succeed after restarting server! Thank you, you made my day! :)

Comment: I just have one more question.. 
Now inside every app, I should create directories: static/static_dirs/name_of_app/my css files
and inside the .html file link it with:
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'name_of_app/style.css' %}"/>

Comment: I am asking this, because this method isn't working for me in my apps

Comment: Nope, you can have a general static_dirs and put all static files on there

Comment: Should I maybe, then, inside my static_dirs create folders for every app and just call it like I did in the comment above? 
I am sorry for bothering and probably noob questions, I started a few days ago to learn Django. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: It depends on you. You can create folder for every app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177747/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-neven).